# updating 2FA for a defunct phone number

Tags: security, google-account, password, password-protection, 2fa

I moved an account from phone `x` to phone `y` and secured the account so that phone `x` had no access anymore.  Next I enabled 2FA through the phone number on the new phone, phone `y` and **discarded** phone `x`.  That worked fine.

Then I changed my phone number without updating the 2FA.

On phone `y` I sent an e-mail to myself to confirm that the account was at least working, which it was.  When I tried to login on a new phone to the account I ran into problems with 2FA because of the now-defunct phone number.  Oddly, the option to hit "tap" on a phone was presented as an option.  However, there was no message on phone `y` about this.  No model was mentioned, so possibly it was an alert for phone `x` for some reason.

I went into account settings on phone `y` and *believe* that added an additional number for `2FA` after entering the pattern to confirm that phone `y` was mine.  I also had a confirmation code sent to a secondary e-mail.  This I thought would be the solution.

Trying to sign-in on phone `z` to this account brought up an option to sign-in, now specifying phone `y` by model.  However, there were no alerts on phone `y` as I would expect to see.  Ultimately, it turned out that I was now signed out of the account on phone `x`.

I had an e-mail sent with a confirmation code, again, and entered the confirmation code.  Now the account is locked for twenty four hours.

Clearly, I should've confirmed that phone `y` was logged into the account and connected.

Unfortunately, when logging into the account on phone `z` the phone number was still listed as the old number.

I'm waiting twenty four hours for an e-mail from Google while they evaluate, but is there something else I could've done here?  Now that I'm logged out of the account on phone `y` it's seemingly now behind a wall of `2FA` with an old phone number.

Comment: I'd suggest checking [Google Account Security settings](https://myaccount.google.com/security), but can you access your Google account in any way?